# How can i make an MDI form inactive when child form is active

Tags: c#, winforms

I placed an MDI form in my application . If i select an option from file menu as New i will have a child form loaded.

My code is as follows to show the child form

```
  private void ShowNewForm(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Form frm in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            if (frm.Text == "Main")
            {
                IsOpen = true;
                frm.Focus();
                break;
            }
        }
        if (IsOpen == false)
        {
            Form childForm = new FrmMain();
            childForm.MdiParent = this;
            childForm.Show();
        }
     }
```

Now what i need is when the child form is in active state i would like to have my MDI inactive until and unless the user closes the child form.

Generally for forms  we will write

```
        frm.showDialog()
```

So how to resolve this

Comment: I'm not clear as to why do you need child forms to be MDI, when you're using them as Dialog forms? Why not childForm.ShowDialog()?

Comment: If i use childform.showdialog() i am getting an error as Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog.

Comment: I'm not sure it is possible or not, but I think your ui design is interesting. I didn't see this approach in any other application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

give like this

```
if (IsOpen == false)
        {

    Form childForm = new FrmMain();
         childForm.TopLevel=true;
         childForm.ShowInTaskbar=false;
         childForm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

Comment: But the form will not be inside MDI if we move the from right

Comment: by giving TopLevel=true,MDI inactive until and unless the user closes the child form.But its not having MDI parent

Comment: But inorder to make the form inside the MDI can't we do this.

Comment: set the childForm's ShowInTaskbar property to false.

Comment: Even then if i move my child form it is moving ouside the MDI.

Comment: I think MDIChild forms cannot be shown as Modal. You will have to create a non-mdi child form which can be shown as modal.

Answer (score 2):

This is fundamental about MDI, a child form can not be made modal.  You *have* to use ShowDialog() and make sure you don't set the MdiParent property.  Such a dialog is not constrained by the boundaries of the MDI parent, you can use the StartPosition property to get it centered.  Like this:

```
        using (var dlg = new Form2()) {
            dlg.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
            if (dlg.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK) {
                // Use dialog properties
                //...
            }
        }
```

Of course, you don't have to check anymore whether the form already exists, it is modal.