# Passing the values of my TextBox from Form1 to form2 by clicking button

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I want to pass values of my TextBox from Form1 to Form2.

And this message appear.

```
"Form that is not a top-level form cannot be displayed as a modal dialog box. Remove the form from any parent form before calling showDialog."
```

Here is my Code of `Form1`:

```
private void btnAddReceipt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.Hide();
        using (var Ticket = new frmCustomerTicket())
        {
            Ticket.CustomerID = txtCustNo.Text;
            ShowDialog();

        }

    }
```

Here is My Code in Form2

```
    public string CustomerID { get; set; }


    private void frmCustomerTicket_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        txtCustID.Text = CustomerID;        

    }
```

Comment: Is it only one value that you are sending from one form to another.If it is only one textbox value why don't you use session variable  like Session["txtValue"]=txtCustID.Text and access this session variable in Form2.

Comment: @Gayatri, it sounds like its a winforms application so you wont be able to use Session

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void btnAddReceipt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{



    this.Hide();
    var Ticket = new frmCustomerTicket();
        Ticket.CustomerID = txtCustNo.Text;
        Ticket.Show();



}
```

**Upate**
Remove the using block it will cause the Form2 element to dispose as soon as it falls out of scope.

Comment: When I click the button it still display the same Form.

Comment: I guess I dont understand I thought the problem was you couldnt display the form.

Comment: Are you calling ShowDialog() from a form that is a Dialog, or is it a top level form?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it on the constructor?
I mean you can have this on ur form 2:

```
public partial class MyForm: Form
{
   string myvar = string.Empty;
   public MyForm(string a)
   {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.myvar = a;
   }
}
```

and in your form1 you could have:

```
using (var Ticket = new frmCustomerTicket(txtCustNo.Text))
    {
        Ticket.ShowDialog();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

oh the click event of the button of first form do:

```
        Form2 F2 = new F2(this);
        F2.Show();
        this.Hide();
```

then in second form initialize the first form

```
    FormFirst F1 = new FormFirst();

    public From2(FormFirst form1)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        F1 = form1;
    }
     textboxt2.text = F1.textbox.Text;
```

***Don't forget to make the modifier of the textbox of first form to public***

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is not about **passing values between** forms. I think it's about MDI Parent & Child forms. By definition, an MDI child form is not modal. Take a look at these links:
[How can i make an MDI form inactive when child form is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725497/how-can-i-make-an-mdi-form-inactive-when-child-form-is-active)
[ShowDialog with MdiParent Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9354766/showdialog-with-mdiparent-issue-vbnet)
[Call an Childform in MDIParent Form using ShowDialog()](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/b58e65a4-a88b-4106-bb6b-89478771e81d/call-an-childform-in-mdiparent-form-using-showdialog)